# How do I install GIMP 2.7 on ubuntu 11.10 64 bit?

Tags: 11.10, 64-bit, gimp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install Gimp 2.7?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68001/how-do-i-install-gimp-2-7)
>   [Can i install Gimp 2.7 in ubuntu 11.10 64bit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70748/can-i-install-gimp-2-7-in-ubuntu-11-10-64bit)

I looked at this question [How do I install Gimp 2.7?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68001/how-do-i-install-gimp-2-7), but it wasn't helpful, as its solution was to just install gimp 2.6. Do I need to compile it from source in some way?

Comment: [How do I install Gimp 2.7?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/68001/68032#68032)

Answer (score 0):

Follow this guide: 
[Install GIMP 2.7.1 on Lucid Lynx using PPA](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/12047/install-gimp-2.7.1-on-lucid-lynx-using-ppa/)

Good luck! :)

Comment: And that will work with ubuntu 11.10?

Comment: No, thats is the wrong build (32bits) and its the wrong Ubuntu version.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this guide:

http://blog.bloke.com/2010/06/howto-build-gimp-2-7-1-from-source-step-by-step-ubuntu/

but used babl version 0.1.4, gegl version 0.1.6, and gimp version 2.7.3.